# Suppress separator in paste when values are missing

Tags: r, paste, ggplot2

This is my data structure that I read into a dataframe.

```
treatment  egf       mean      se
10 uM PP2            -697.25   14124.349
10 uM PP2  1 nM EGF  14715.50  8862.012
DMSO                 58589.25  7204.824
DMSO       1 nM EGF  87852.00  12149.159
```

The combination of the treatment and egf columns represent the unique id for each column.  I would like to create a column that combines these so that I can have one column that uniquely represents each row.  However, because of the missing values in the EGF column, when I use paste, it does this annoying thing:

```
>paste(rawp$treatment, rawp$egf, sep=" + ")
[1] "10 uM PP2 + "         "10 uM PP2 + 1 nM EGF" "DMSO + "             
[4] "DMSO + 1 nM EGF"
```

where it will still place the separator there when the value is missing.  I would like for it to read:

```
[1] "10 uM PP2"         "10 uM PP2 + 1 nM EGF" "DMSO"             
[4] "DMSO + 1 nM EGF"
```

How can I do this?

The whole reason I want to do this is because I want to plot the data with ggplot and it seems it requires only 1 unique column when specifying the x axis.

```
ggplot(data=rawp, aes(x=treatment, y=mean)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

So if you also know of an alternative way to use combined columns to specify the category on the x axis, that would be helpful.

Comment: If your specific goal is to use the final result for `ggplot2`, you may want to take a look at Hadley's `reshape2` package as well http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reshape2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would have been nice to use `sep = ifelse(egf == "", "", " + ")` but the `sep` argument to `paste` cannot be a vector. The solution: pass it as a regular argument!

```
with(rawp, paste0(treatment, ifelse(egf == "", "", " + "), egf))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can strip out the "+" after pasting:

```
sub(" \\+ $", "", paste(rawp$treatment, rawp$egf, sep=" + "))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it's harder to duplicate your example, I made my own:

```
d <- data.frame(a=c('a', 'b', ''), b=c('c', 'd', 'e'))
```

What you have:

```
paste(d$a, d$b, sep=' + ')
## [1] "a + c" "b + d" " + e"
```

What you want:

```
unlist(apply(d[1:2], 1, function(x) paste(x[x!=''], collapse=' + ')))
## [1] "a + c" "b + d" "e"
```

The solution is similar if you have `NA` instead of `''` as the blank value.  Use `!is.na(x)` instead of `x!=''` in that case.

This extends to the case where you have more than two columns, and where you might have missing values in any column:

```
d1 <- data.frame(a=c('a', 'b', ''), b=c('c', 'd', 'e'), c=c('', 'f', ''))
unlist(apply(d1, 1, function(x) paste(x[x!=''], collapse=' + ')))
## [1] "a + c"     "b + d + f" "e"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a great example of when `ifelse` would work nicely:

```
ifelse(rawp$egf=="", paste(rawp$treatment), 
                     paste(rawp$treatment, rawp$egf, sep=" + "))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` to take each line of the data.frame and strip out all elements of 0 length, then use the `collapse` argument to bring back to a single string:

```
apply(rawp[1:2],1,function(x) paste(x[nchar(x)>0],collapse=" + "))
[1] "10 uM PP2"            "10 uM PP2 + 1 nM EGF" "DMSO"                
[4] "DMSO + 1 nM EGF"
```